# How can i save the value of route parameter that i get from a user and save it in order to user for other components?

Tags: angular

I have a list of users, i am able to click on one of them and retrieve a specific id(codSoggetto) and then route to another component with that id using route params. That id i want to use to other components how can i do that? How can i save it or use for other components?

```
    export class ListaUtentiComponent implements OnInit {
  userList: Array<List>;
  public itemcodSoggetto;

  constructor(private _userService: UserService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCafUserList();
   
    let codSoggetto = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('codSoggetto');
    this.itemcodSoggetto = codSoggetto;


    
  }

  getCafUserList(): void {
    this._userService
    .getCafUserList()
    .subscribe(res => this.userList = res);
  }

  onSelect(item){
    this.router.navigate(['/homeb', item.codSoggetto]);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can store the id in localStorage and then get it using the method getItem inside all the components you want.

Comment: Thanks, it works woth local Storage